# Buscar Caracteres Específicos em Aquivo TXT Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Tenho uma base de dados contento atos normativos (leis, decretos, portarias, processos, etc). Esta base está no formato `.txt` e não segue um padrão de estruturação.

[Exemplo de uma Portaria](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1odZmlD8YUVCqFtmKfjleUGzY5-gOj8ae/view?usp=sharing):

```
PORTARIA Nº 392, DE 9 DE SETEMBRO DE 2021
```

Os textos estão completamente sem formatação, com muitos espaços e quebras de linhas que dificultam suas análises.

A grande maioria desses atos, em seu corpo, fazem referência a outros atos como:

> O SECRETÁRIO DE DEFESA AGROPECUÁRIA DO MINISTÉRIO DA AGRICULTURA, PECUÁRIA E ABASTECIMENTO, no uso da atribuição que lhe conferem os art. 21 e 63 do Anexo I do **Decreto nº 10.253**, de 20 de fevereiro de 2020, tendo em vista o disposto na **Lei nº 8.171**, de 17 de janeiro de 1991, na **Lei nº 13.874**, de 20 de setembro de 2019, no **Decreto nº 10.178**, de 18 de dezembro de 2019, e o que consta do **Processo SEI nº 21000.058030 /2020-37**, resolve:...

Eu preciso extrair dos atos o título e suas referências (caso houver) e criar um arquivo contendo duas colunas. A primeira trazendo sempre o ato em análise e a segunda suas referências. Exemplo usando o trecho acima:

```
| PORTARIA, 392 |         Decreto, 10.253             |
| PORTARIA, 392 |            Lei, 8.171               |
| PORTARIA, 392 |            Lei, 13.874              |
| PORTARIA, 392 |         Decreto, 10.178             |
| PORTARIA, 392 | Processo SEI, 21000.058030 /2020-37 |
| PORTARIA, 392 |        Revogado Lei, 14.133         |
```

O padrão que observei para a possível realização da tarefa é a sequência de caracteres `Nº`.

Verifiquei com um profissional do direito do sobre os comentários feitos. O Processo SEI não entrará no arquivo que será gerado, pois ele não faz sentido. Quanto aos outros atos que aparecem no decorrer do texto A MAIORIA segue o seguinte padrão **nome do ato** **n°** **0.000** ou **00.000**.
Tambem me disse ser importante trazer informações como **Revogado** pela **Lei** nº **14.133**
O ato que vier a frente de **Revogado**

Alguém teria uma ideia de como posso estar executando este tipo de tarefa?

Comment: Sem um critério claro, fica complicado sugerir algo. O que pode ter antes do nº? Somente "Lei", "Decreto" e "Processo SEI"? E depois, são números em formatos específicos (ex: quantidade X de dígitos, seguido de ponto, barra, traço, mais Y dígitos, etc)? Com critérios mais claros, daria para sugerir uma solução. Poderia [edit] a pergunta e colocar esses detalhes?

Comment: Depois da edição, volto a insistir: se "_não segue um padrão de estruturação_", então qualquer tentativa de extrair os dados pode dar falsos positivos (pegar o que não precisa) ou falsos negativos (deixar de fora alguns trechos válidos). **Deve ter** pelo menos alguns formatos mais comuns (por exemplo, texto específico, vírgula, X dígitos, ponto/traço/hífen, Y dígitos, etc). Tente primeiro ver quais são esses formatos, a partir daí dá para sugerir algo.

Comment: Nesse caso, basta [edit] a pergunta e colocar esses critérios

Comment: @hkotsubo tudo bem? Verifiquei com um profissional do direito do sobre os comentários feitos. O Processo SEI não entrará no arquivo que será gerado, pois ele não faz sentido. Quanto aos outros atos que aparecem no decorrer do texto A MAIORIA segue o seguinte padrão **nome do ato** **n°** **0.000** ou **00.000**.
Me disse ser importante trazer informações como **Revogado** pela **Lei** nº **14.133**

Comment: No início sempre é PORTARIA, e o ato sempre é Decreto, Lei ou Processo SEI, ou tem mais outros tipos? Aliás, o formato do Processo SEI não condiz com o que vc disse (não é "00.000", tem mais dígitos aí, além do espaço, barra e hífen). E como vc está lendo o arquivo? É um txt, exatamente no formato indicado? Por exemplo, depois de "Decreto nº" tem uma quebra de linha e vários espaços antes do número "10.253", vai ser assim mesmo? E no arquivo do link não tem "Processo SEI", tem somente "Processo". No caso do "Revogado", depois pode ser pelo, pela, por, etc, não?

Comment: Enfim, um jeito de fazer seria assim: https://ideone.com/0VDlTI - não sei se cobre todos os casos porque parece ter mais variações que ainda não foram descobertas.

Comment: @hkotsubo, pode ser PORTARIA, LEI, DECRETO, MEDIDA PROVISÓRIA, REGIMENTO, RESOLUÇÃO... O Processo SEI não entrará. Na verdade, nenhum tipo de Processo.
Sobre os arquivos sim, estão todos em txt e com esse formato bagunçado.
E sim, no caso do "Revogado", pode aparecer **pelo**, **pela**, **por**...

Answer (score -2):

**Atualizado em 1/9/2022 baseado na regex que o [hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) postou no comentário**

Baseado no exemplo que você passou.

```
>>> txt = "O SECRETÁRIO DE DEFESA AGROPECUÁRIA DO MINISTÉRIO DA AGRICULTURA, PECUÁRIA E ABASTECIMENTO, no uso da atribuição que lhe conferem os art. 21 e 63 do Anexo I do Decreto nº 10.253, de 20 de fevereiro de 2020, tendo em vista o disposto na Lei nº 8.171, de 17 de janeiro de 1991, na Lei nº 13.874, de 20 de setembro de 2019, no Decreto nº 10.178, de 18 de dezembro de 2019, e o que consta do Processo SEI nº 21000.058030 /2020-37, resolve:.O SECRETÁRIO DE DEFESA AGROPECUÁRIA DO MINISTÉRIO DA AGRICULTURA, PECUÁRIA E ABASTECIMENTO, no uso da atribuição que lhe conferem os art. 21 e 63 do Anexo I do Decreto nº 10.253, de 20 de fevereiro de 2020, tendo em vista o disposto na Lei nº 8.171, de 17 de janeiro de 1991, na Lei nº 13.874, de 20 de setembro de 2019, no Decreto nº 10.178, de 18 de dezembro de 2019, e o que consta do Processo SEI nº 21000.058030 /2020-37, resolve:."

>>> import re

>>> r = re.findall(r'(Decreto|Lei|Processo SEI) nº (\d+(?: ?[./-]\d+)*)', txt)

>>> print(r)
[('Decreto', '10.253'), ('Lei', '8.171'), ('Lei', '13.874'), ('Decreto', '10.178'), ('Processo SEI', '21000.058030 /2020-37'), ('Decreto', '10.253'), ('Lei', '8.171'), ('Lei', '13.874'), ('Decreto', '10.178'), ('Processo SEI', '21000.058030 /2020-37')]
```

Comment: Pra pegar o Processo SEI poderia ser algo assim: https://ideone.com/BOo0mI - claro, se considerar o texto que está na pergunta e assumindo que não tem outras variações no formato.